# Complex SQL query through join table

Tags: sql

I have a table PC with 3 fiedls: `join_c_id`, `join_pid` and type.
`join_c_id` is an FK to a table called `clients`.
`join_p_id` is an FK to a table called `parkings`.

type can be 1,2,3.

I have to
When I delete a record from parking I have to:
1) Delete the association between parking and clients where type = 1
2) Delete all the other associations to `clients` (type != 1) BUT only if those clients have
no other association to other parkings.

Let say I have the PC as:

```
`join_c_id` | `join_p_id` | type
---------------------------------
    1           1           1
    2           1           2
    3           1           3
    3           1           1
```

When I delete the record with id 1 from `parkings`, I want to delete `clients` with id 1,2 but not 3 (because 3 has another association). Can somebody help me with some hint?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to do the query...

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What should the table look like afterward?  Are you trying to delete all records where `join_p_id = 1` (as opposed to `join_c_id`, wherein the follow-on effects seem confusing)?

Comment: First, I have to delete all record with join_p_id = 1. Then I want to delete FROM clients all records that have no association in PC...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to exclude the cid with the type that not only 1 & 2 , cheer

```
DELETE FROM tbl_sample
WHERE PID = 1
AND [TYPE] IN(1,2)
AND [CID] NOT IN ((select CID FROM TBL_SAMPLE WHERE [TYPE] NOT IN (1,2)))
```

References : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/adffb/10

Answer (score 0):

```
 DELETE FROM clients WHERE id IN  
             (SELECT join_c_id FROM PC WHERE  
                     PC.join_pratiche_id=%d AND  
                     join_c_id NOT IN 
                     (SELECT join_c_id FROM PC WHERE 
                      join_p_id != %d)
              )
```

where `%d == <the id of parking>` I am deleting (=1 in the example).